# Server reading a command line argument passed to the client

Tags: c, sockets

I want to pass an argument to the client, send it to the server, then print it there, currently I am getting no output.

Current codes:

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>

#define PORT 8080 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 


    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("Invalid address \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("Connection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
      int i;
     if(argc>=2){
     for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    if(write( sock, argv[i], 1 + strlen( argv[i] ))<0)
    {
    printf("Error in write() ! %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }
}
}
    return 0; 
}
```

Server:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include<errno.h>
#define PORT 8080 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 


    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 


    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 


    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                                 sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

valread = read(new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
puts("The client sent the value: ");
int* valuerec=(int *)buffer;
int val2=*valuerec;

    return 0; 
}
```

Currently I am getting no number as an output, how can I do fix this? Ultimately my goal would be to send and receive multiple arguments but for now I am only sending one.

Comment: @snr sorry I am new to this, I would be glad if you could suggest solutions.

Comment: should check return value of valread as is in write.

Comment: just did that and got no error and no output

Comment: OT: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Connection Failed \n");` and similar statements.   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  The function: `perror( "your error message" );`  performs both parts of this functionality I.E. `perror( "connect failed" );`

Comment: Please describe what exactly the expected output is and what the current output is and what code you are talking about (there are two). I can not find a line in your code that would print a number.

Comment: the client is sending 0 or more text strings, including the trailing NUL byte.  The server is ONLY processing a single short text string.  However, the server receives a text string and then treating it as a `int`  That will not work, need to convert the text string to an `int`  perhaps via  the function: `strtol()` or `atoi()`

Comment: OT: the server code signature for `main()` has two parameters that are not used.  This causes the compiler to output to warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `valread = read(new_socket , buffer, 1024);`  the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`.  The code should be checking `valread`: If <0 then handle error.  If ==0 then client disconnected.  If > 0 then some message received.

Comment: OT: suggest client NOT send the trailing NUL byte

Comment: regarding: *but for now I am only sending one.*  Actually, the client is sending ALL the command line arguments, including the name of the client executable.  Remember that `argv[0]` is a pointer to a char string that contains the name of the executable that is being run

Comment: @JensHarms I am expected to enter an integer from the command line to the client program then make the server print it with a line(not passed from the client) before it, the line is printing but the integer isn't

Comment: @user3629249 I implented the improvements you talked about thank you. Can you help with the receiving end? like what to modify and such to receive everything

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired server functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. properly handles errors
5. uses an appropriate signature for function: `main()`
6. does not include header files those contents are not used
7. uses meaningful names rather than 'magic' numbers
8. uses appropriate horizontal spacing for readability
9. properly NUL terminates the input buffer
10. note the function: `atoi()` does not indicate when an error occurs, so suggest using `strtol()` instead
11. properly cleared the struct `address` before setting some of the fields

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>  



#define PORT 8080 
#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN 1025

int main( void ) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket;

    struct sockaddr_in address; 

    if ( ( server_fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror( "socket failed" ); 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
    } 

    int opt = 1; 
    if ( setsockopt( server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt) ) ) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt failed" ); 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
    } 

    memset( &address, 0, sizeof( address ) );
    address.sin_family      = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY ); 
    address.sin_port        = htons( PORT ); 

    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof( address );
    if ( bind( server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, addrlen ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror( "bind failed" ); 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
    } 

    if ( listen( server_fd, 3 ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror( "listen failed" ); 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
    } 

    if (( new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen ) ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror( "accept failed" ); 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
    } 

    ssize_t valread; 
    char buffer[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ] = { 0 };

    if( ( valread = read( new_socket, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LEN -1 ) ) > 0 )
    {  // then read successful
        buffer[ valread ] = '\0';
        int value = atoi( buffer );
        printf( "The client sent the string: %s, which began with integer value: %d\n", buffer, value );
    }

    else if( ! valread )
    {
        puts( "client hungup" );
    }

    else
    {
        perror( "read failed" );
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Output is the following regardless of what integer I input:
`The client sent the string: ./cl, which began with integer value: 0`